# Video Manipulation

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, video-processing

Before a couple days ago I had never used OpenCV or done any video processing.  I've been asked to computationally overlay a video based upon some user inputs and build a new video with the overlays incorporated for download in AVI format.  Essentially, the goal is to have a form that takes as input 3 images (icon, screenshot #1, screenshot #1) and 3 text inputs and overlays the original video with them.  Here is a [link to the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDMrr3KMOzA).  When the video is running you'll notice the icon in the center of the iPhone at the beginning is stretched and pulled.  I've been iteratively testing OpenCV methods by breakding down the video frame by frame and doing stuff to each one, then rebuilding (obviously this is probably the only way to successfully rebuild a video with OpenCV with edits, but anyway).  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzJ1WAWUfEc) video is one I overlayed a colored circle that moves back and forth with.

```
# the method I've been using
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
cap = cv.VideoCapture('the_vid.avi')
flag, frame = cap.read()
width = np.size(frame,1)
height = np.size(frame,0)
writer = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('I','4','2','0'), fps=35, (width,height), 1)

while True:
    flag, frame = cap.read()
    if flag == 0:
        break
    x = width/2
    y = height/2
    # add a line or circle or something
                    origin radius
    cv.circle(frame, (x,y), 20, (0,0,255), -1)
    # write our new frame
    writer.write(frame)
```

Now we've got an output of this very large uncompressed AVI file which can be compressed using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i output.avi -vcodec msmpeg4v2 compressed_output.avi
```

Ok, so that's the method I've been using to rebuild this video, and from that method I'm not seeing it possible to take a static image and stretch it around like is shown in the first 90 frames or so.  The only other possibility I saw was maybe doing something like below.  If you can tell me if there is even a way to implement this pseudo-code that would be awesome, I'm thinking it will be extremely difficult:

```
# example for the first image and first few seconds of video only

first_image = cv.imread('user_uploaded_icon.png')
flag, first_frame = cap.read()

# section of the frame that contains the original icon
the_section = algorithm_to_get_array_of_original_icon_in_first_frame(first_frame)
rows, cols = the_section.shape

# somehow find the array within the first image that is the same size as the_section
# containing JUST the icon
icon = array_of_icon(first_image)

# build a blank image with the size of the original icon in the current frame

blank_image = np.zeros((rows,cols,3),np.uint8)

for i in xrange(row):
    for j in xrange(col):
        blank_image[i,j] = icon[i,j]
```

What seems like it might not work about this is the fact that the_section in the first_frame will be stretched to different dimensions than the static image...so I'm not sure if there is ANY viable way to handle this.  I appreciate all the time saving help in advance.